# Should an internal DialogFragment class be static or not?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

This is a snippet of code from my project that I am using to learn Android:

```
private void enableLocationSettings() {
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
}

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class EnableGpsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Tytuł")
            .setMessage("wiadomosc")
            .setPositiveButton("odpal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    enableLocationSettings();
                }

            })
            .create();
    }
}
```

As you can see I must add `@SuppressLint` to make my app work but on the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) this annotation wasn't necessary.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are my imports:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The example doesn't have those annotations because the class is in its own file. This means it is *independent* of the Activity that uses the Fragment.

In your case, your Fragment is inside an Activity and doesn't use the static modifier. This means it is tied to the Activity instance.

Having the Fragment depend on the Activity instance is a bad idea, both these classes have complex lifecyles (especially since Activities get destroyed and recreated quite often) and should be independent of each other.

You will need to make `EnableGpsDialogFragment`'s modifier `static`.

```
public static class EnableGpsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
```

A `static` class does not depend on the enclosing class' instance, so the warning will go away.

For more information, read the Java tutorial on [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Edit in response to your edit:
Now that the classes don't depend on each other's instance, you will have to get out an instance of `YourActivity` so you can call `enabledLocationSettings()` one way is by casting and will only work if `EnableGpsDialogFragment` is only used by `YourActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  enableLocationSettings();
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  ((YourActivity)getActivity()).enableLocationSettings();
}
```

If this Fragment will be used by multiple Activities, you should [create an `interface` to be implemented by each Activity instead](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: Thanks but adding static modifier to EnableGpsDialogFragment is forcing me to add static modifier to private void enableLocationSettings(). And if I add it a new error appears : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity

Comment: @szpic well that's because your **edit** to your question now includes a call to  `enableLocationSettings();`

Comment: To circumvent this, you can use a weak reference to whatever is needed from the activity. Then before using, check that it is still valid. This should be set every time the activity is destroyed/created to ensure it is valid. To add about static fragments: They can leak memory in this context if not created statically as it's possible for them to hold a reference to and old activity that is no longer otherwise accessible and should have been garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day. I wish I could give you more up votes!

Answer (score 4):

All DialogFragments should be public and - if an inner class - static. They should also have a public no-arg constructor, and rely only on setArguments() for parameter passing.

Failing to comply to this has for some time produced a Lint warning, that you could suppress if you really wanted to, but starting from the Android support library v25 and on, you will actually get an exception if trying to show a DialogFragment that doesn't comply to these rules:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TestActivity$TestDialogFrament must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state.`

The reason is, as stated, that the OS must be able to recreate all fragments in case something like a low-memory situation forces it to destroy fragments when an app is put into the background. When the app is put in the foreground again, the fragments should be possible to re-create from the serialized application state, and that is not possible for non-static inner classes other than from an instance of the enclosing outer class, and the re-creation is not done from that context.

Unfortunately this makes things more complex for dialogs, since it's usually very convenient to just create an anonymous sub-class that overrides onCreateDialog. However, such a dialog would not be able to re-create at all.

Comment: Low-memory situations are a real threat since we have at least 2GB RAM in cheap smartphones... :) I never understood why Google wants to recreate my dialog fragments if they had to destroy them - I can do it on my own and already do so (I use v23 and won't upgrade).

Comment: Well, partly because so many apps are misbehaving and are basically running all the time, or are being constantly restarted due to frequent broadcast intents. This is being severely addressed in Android N and O. If 50 apps want to run all the time, there will be a lot of swapping in and out apps from memory. Also, remember that on a 1080p screen, one single bitmap is 8 MB. And I'm not quite sure I understand why you would want to re-create state yourself completely manually, but we all have our treats...

Answer (score 1):

It should not be !

From my point of view, I don't want my DialogFragment (your NetworkConnectionError) to be static because I want to be able to call variables or methods of my containing class (Activity) from it.
So It won't be static.
But I don't want to generate memoryLeaks neither.
So what is the solution ?
Simple, when you go in onStop, insure you kill your DialogFragment, it's as simple as that.
So the code looks like something like that:

```
public class CarActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

/**
 * The DialogFragment networkConnectionErrorDialog 
 */
private NetworkConnectionError  networkConnectionErrorDialog ;
//...  your code ...//
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //invalidate the DialogFragment to avoid stupid memory leak
    if (networkConnectionErrorDialog != null) {
        if (networkConnectionErrorDialog .isVisible()) {
            networkConnectionErrorDialog .dismiss();
        }
        networkConnectionErrorDialog = null;
    }
}
/**
 * The method called to display your dialogFragment
 */
private void onDeleteCurrentCity(){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
     networkConnectionErrorDialog =(DeleteAlert)fm.findFragmentByTag("networkError");
    if(networkConnectionErrorDialog ==null){
        networkConnectionErrorDialog =new DeleteAlert();
    }
    networkConnectionErrorDialog .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "networkError");
}
```

And that way you avoid memory leaks (because it's bad) and you insure you don't have a fucking static fragment that cannot access your activity's fields and methods.
This is the good way to handle that problem, from my point of view.

Comment: DialogFragments *should* be public static classes with a public no-op constructor, simple as that. If not, the system will not be able to re-create the fragment if that's needed in a low-memory situation etc. Also, starting from support library v25 your app will crash if trying to show a DialogFragment which does not fulfill the above mentioned constraints:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TestActivity$TestDialogFrament must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state.`

Comment: oops, typo: no-op -> no-arg

Comment: No. They shouldn't. I can re-create them by myself.

Comment: Again, why would you prefer that in most normal situations?