# Android app build throws error for release, debug doesn't

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an Android app that I've been working on (it's a project I adopted so most of the code isn't mine - which isn't helping :P) and I'm running into an issue.

The app builds just fine in debug mode (building and installing it on a device for testing). But when I try to build a release it fails.

This is the error in the gradle console:

> Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
>
> > Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

And this is what it says in Messages Gradle Build:

> Error:Error: This fragment class should be public ([com.company.appname].fragments.create_dilemma.CreateDilemmaFragment1_2.UploadDialogFragment) [ValidFragment]

This is the offending line:

```
private class UploadDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

So I change private to public and then it complains that it should be a static class. Thing is, it looks like this class isn't supposed to be static because AS isn't happy with pretty much any of the code as soon as I make it static.

So I'm left with a few questions:

1. How is this only an issue for the release build and not for debug?
2. Is there a way to ignore this 'error' when building a release?
3. There must be a reason for this error, right? Why is it ignored for debug and not for release? What are the up/downsides of fixing this? Because the app works just fine as far as I can tell so I don't really see the problem..?

PS: My java skills are so-so. I know my way around the language but I have a lot to learn when it comes to knowing what a static class exactly is and what is allowed and what not, why it is(n't), etc. So plz be gentle, I'm trying to learn this stuff :)

Update: As per request here's the relevant part of my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[com.pany.appname]"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Comment: add your build.gradle file might have some config related to release build.

Comment: Added it. But I can't find anything in there that explains the difference between debug and release building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm summarizing some of the answers given in this post to collect them in one. Makes it easier to accept it, too :)

**-- WHY THE QUICK FIX IS NOT A REAL FIX --**

It's POSSIBLE to have this project build a release apk successfully (see below). But it's probably not a good idea to just do that and not think about it.

As pointed out by X3Btel:

> Fragments needs to be public because systems recreates them on orientation change. The other warning is because non static inner classes holds reference to their outter class, hence it creates memmory leak. Best course of action would be move the fragment to his own class. Or make it public and ignore the lint warning (this may create memmory leak but keeping it private may crash the app)

In my case I can keep it non-static and circumvent memory leaks by making sure I finish the fragment whenever its parent activity is finished. It's not pretty but it'll fix the memory leak and I don't have to refactor A LOT of code I didn't write. That said: It apparently is bad practice to have an activity or fragment and declare another activity/fragment as an inner class because of the way the Android lifecycle works.

Here's some more reading on the topic which I found useful (and only found AFTER I posted this question):

[Should an internal DialogFragment class be static or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414908/should-an-internal-dialogfragment-class-be-static-or-not)

**-- THE QUICK FIXES --**

**1) Don't check for lint errors during build (as pointed out by Jay Shan)**

Add lintOptions -> checkReleaseBuilds option to build.gradle

```
android {
  // ..
  lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
  }
}
```

**2) Check for errors but keep building even when they are found**

This is probably a little bit safer than not checking for errors at all because at least you'll get a warning somewhere in the log output.

Add lintOptions -> abortOnError option to build.gradle

```
android {
  // ..
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}
```

**3) Supress the error where it happens**

I find this to be the preferred method because you can still use lint for finding other problems AND have it abort when that happens BUT at the same time you can ignore things you've checked.

In my case I had to add @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") before the offending line:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
private class UploadDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
{ 
  // ..
}
```

**UPDATE 2018/01/04**

If you use a recent version of Android Support Library (and its Fragment implementation instead of the OS's) your app will crash (IllegalStateException) if you try to initialize that Fragment. Suppressing the warning will not help you. You'll just have to fix the underlying problem, make the inner class public and static, or move the class to a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this option in android block of build.gradle section

```
        lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
```

Comment: I went with "abortOnError false" so it'll still show the error but your answer does work. Thanks!

Comment: One other possibility is putting @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") before the offending line ("private class UploadDialogFragment [...]"). It is a temporary solution but at least it has less impact than ignoring all errors or not checking for them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Jay Shan`s answer should work. But better to understand what is the problem. Fragments needs to be public because systems recreates them on orientation change. The other  warning is because non static inner classes holds reference  to their outter class, hence it creates memmory leak.
Best course of action would be move the fragment to his own class. Or make it public and ignore the lint warning (this may create memmory leak but keeping it private may crash the app)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. This app doesn't do orientation changes so I guess it's not a huge issue atm but it's good to keep that in mind. Well, fixed a bug and in the process I found some other completely unrelated code that needs refactoring :D