# Error while generating signed APK in Android

Tags: android

I have implemented an Android app all functionalities are working fine. But while I am trying to sign the APK:

It shows error like this:

> "Error:This fragment inner class should be static (MyFragment) [ValidFragment]"

I can't make this inner class as static because I have to access methods and variables from non-static also.

Comment: Try making it in a seperate file

Comment: Disable lint option by following this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971813/android-app-build-throws-error-for-release-debug-doesnt/38972017?noredirect=1#comment65304346_38972017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
        }

It is working fine
Thank you so much.